# Formal concept analysis with Elasticsearch

Tags: algorithm, elasticsearch, search, concept

I would like to implement a Google-like search with Elasticsearch like this example :

[image: Google like search]

For example, if I have this collection of documents :

```
[
   {
      "title":"Some Example 1",
      "tags":[
         "tag1",
         "tag2",
         "tag3"
      ],
      "difficulty":"easy"
   },
   {
      "title":"Some Example 2",
      "tags":[
         "tag3"
      ],
      "difficulty":"normal"
   },
   {
      "title":"Some Example 3",
      "tags":[
         "tag3",
         "tag1"
      ],
      "difficulty":"normal"
   }
]
```

I would like to have a [Completion Suggester](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html#completion-suggester) that does a "Formal concept analysis" on the "tags" field of each document 
( in addition to using filters on other fields (like the "difficulty" one) ).

After reading part of the Elasticsearch docs, the [Adjacency Matrix Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-adjacency-matrix-aggregation.html) doesn't seem to handle this complex search algorithm.
Do you have any alternatives ?

Thanks for your help :)